# How to link a bank account to my website for payment?

Tags: website, web

There are lots of services taking care of this matter like paypal or other online shop CMS. But mine is a more essential question: How do I do it without any of other 3rd party softwares? Typically, what I want is when people click a button, they be brought to a page to input their credit card information for payment to my account. My bank is Chase, I think they should offer some API for this, but I couldn't find it.

I just need a rough direction f. I went to other banks' website but there seems no information regarding this issue and I try to google it but couldn't figure out a good keyword.(anything similar to "online banking" or "online shop" return results flooded by other irrelevant entries)

Comment: Give me all your banking information and I will show you how! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply to your bank and if they approve your application they will create a Virtual POS Account for you and grant you the API which you can access the POS operations like opening transactions, taking credit card payments or partial payments.

Once you get your account created and get the API, the rest is just implementing the protocols requested by API stack.

Long story short, the keyword you are looking for is **Virtual POS**.